# Pandas filter groups into two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a large data set and I'm applying a filter to remove certain groups. I'd like to collect the removed groups in a seperate dataframe so that they can be flagged and followed up by humans. The vast majority of groups pass the filter and I don't want to copy the dataframe. I'm aware I could run the negation of the filter once to collect the small number fails and then run it again in place to leave the passes but it seems reasonable there should be a way of simply splitting the groups into two dataframes.

This is my current code for removing unwanted groups. It removes tracks which have consecutive points further than 0.02 degrees apart.

```py
max_difference_degrees = 0.02
if filter_spurious_points:
   tracks = tracks.groupby('trackid').filter(lambda df: df[['longitude', 'latitude']].diff().abs().max(axis=1).max(axis=0) < max_difference_degrees)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Then don't use filter, rather compute the flag and use it to split the DataFrame:

```
flag = (df.groupby('trackid')[['longitude', 'latitude']]
          .diff().abs().max(axis=1).max(axis=0)
        < max_difference_degrees
       )

out = dict(list(df.groupby(df['trackid'].map(flag))))
```